# Automatically move files with python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu

I am trying to make a python script that will allow me to place music into one large folder so when I run the script it will create folders according to the first part of the music files. So let's say I have a music file called `OMFG - Ice Cream.mp3` I would like to be able to split each music file name so that instead of `OMFG - Ice Cream.mp3` it would chop it off in this case `Ice Cream.mp3` and then it would use `OMFG` to create a folder called that. After it created that folder I would then like to find out a way to then move, in this case `OMFG - Ice Cream.mp3` into the folder that was just created.

Here is my code so far:

```py
import os

# path = "/Users/alowe/Desktop/testdir2"
# os.listdir(path)
songlist = ['OMFG - Ice Cream.mp3', 'OMFG - Hello.mp3', 'Dillistone - Sad & High.mp3']
teststr = str(songlist)
songs = teststr.partition('-')[0]
print ''.join(songs)[2:-1]
```

My main trouble is how to loop through each object in the string.

Thanks, 
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient to use [`pathlib` module for such tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from pathlib import Path

src_dir = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else Path.home() / 'Music'
for path in Path(src_dir).glob('*.mp3'): # list all mp3 files in source directory
    dst_dir, sep, name = path.name.partition('-')
    if sep: # move the mp3 file if the hyphen is present in the name
        dst_dir = path.parent / dst_dir.rstrip()
        dst_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True) # create the leaf directory if necessary
        path.replace(dst_dir / name.lstrip()) # move file
```

Example:

```
$ python3.5 move-mp3.py /Users/alowe/Desktop/testdir2
```

It moves `OMFG - Ice Cream.mp3` to `OMFG/Ice Cream.mp3`.

---

If you want to move `OMFG - Ice Cream.mp3` to `OMFG/OMFG - Ice Cream.mp3`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import sys
from pathlib import Path

src_dir = Path('/Users/alowe/Desktop/testdir2') # source directory
for path in src_dir.glob('*.mp3'): # list all mp3 files in source directory
    if '-' in path.name: # move the mp3 file if the hyphen is present in the name
        dst_dir = src_dir / path.name.split('-', 1)[0].rstrip() # destination
        dst_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True) # create the leaf directory if necessary
        path.replace(dst_dir / path.name) # move file
```

Comment: Your script worked great!!! But Is there a way so that I do not have to type `/Users/alowe/Desktop/testdir2` each time I type the command? Maybe by adding the folder path within the Python script?

Comment: @Alex: yes, if you want to hardcode the path; put it instead of `Path.home()/'Music'` in the script.

Comment: Also instead of moving  `OMFG - Ice Cream.mp3` to `OMFG/Ice Cream.mp3` can I move it to `OMFG/OMFG - Ice Cream.mp3` if there is a way how?

Comment: @Alex: I've updated the answer. To keep old name, use `dst_dir / path.name` instead of `dst_dir / name.lstrip()`.

Comment: This script does not work on `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS` because it only has `Python 3.4` what modifications would I need to make in order to make this script work with python 3.4?

Comment: @Alex: consider the code in my answer to be an executable pseudo-code (it should be clear what it does and it can be executed (using python3.5 in this case)). It should be simple to adapt it to older `pathlib` versions or even rewrite it using only `os`/`os.path` functions. If you can't then install `pathlib2` that has all the latest features or ask a separate question about *one* **specific** issue that you have with the porting e.g., `exist_ok` parameter was added in Python 3.5 -- if you can't emulate it on earlier Python versions; ask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I figured it out with a little bit of tinkering.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this code that:

- Loops through the list
- Split each element into the list
- Create folder if it does not  exist yet
- Transfer music to that folder

Loops through the list

```
    import os
    import shutil
    songlist = ['OMFG - Ice Cream.mp3', 'OMFG - Hello.mp3', 'Dillistone - Sad & High']
    m_dir = '/path/mainfolder'
    song_loc = '/path/songlocation'

    for song in songlist:
        s = song.split('-')
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(m_dir,s[0])):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(song_loc,song),os.path.join(m_dir,s[0].strip()))
        else:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(m_dir,s[0]))
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(song_loc,song),os.path.join(m_dir,s[0].strip()))
```

Comment: Umm... Did you forget to transfer anything? Say, with `os.rename` or `shutil.move`? I'll grant the questioner was asking for something much simpler, which makes me think they really need to run through a proper Python tutorial.

Comment: I just wrote the pseudocode, assuming he/she already knows the function to transfer. But okay i can edit and add the transferring of files. (Shutil, etc)

Comment: It looked nearly complete, so omitting the last step just seemed odd. No big deal.

Comment: Alright, ill just add the shutil just for the sake of completeness

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes I am fairly new to Python. So what tutorial would you recommend me to do?

Comment: @Alex: If you're going to be writing Python 2 (not really recommended, since it's intentionally denying you access to new features and improvements from the Py3 line), you could go with [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/). Or just get a recent copy of Learning Python, or do run through the [core Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), or a dozen others. I learned it initially from a week long overview at work, but there are a million sources, the key is to keep investigating and learning on your own.

Comment: what error is it producing? @Alex, you can also try to http://www.codecademy.com/ an interactive website for learning python

Comment: @anon I am getting this `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Shinedown - 45.mp3'` Shinedown - 45.mp3' is the music file.

Comment: @anon I am thinking about buying this book for learning python [Learning Python](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Python-Mark-Lutz-ebook/dp/B00DDZPC9S/ref=mt_kindle?_encoding=UTF8&me=). I am also going to try out [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com) and also [treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/tracks/learn-python)

Comment: @anon When I run your script it creates the **directories** depending on the name before the `-` but it also creates a **file** which whose name is the name before the `-` but it does not move the music files into the newly created folders.

Comment: you could change the shutil.copy to shutil.move, that way it will cut the file and paste it to the created directory.